# Can I fix the empty space when performing "show windows side-by-side" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

When I log in, my windows are arranged as expected when I perform the function "show windows side-by-side".  After using the desktop for a while (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours), when I would like the perform this task, it is as if there are "ghost" windows that take up space on the screen.

The windows are arranged with empty space remaining, like it was arranging windows that aren't open, or are invisible.
[image]

Is there a way I can fix the empty space when performing "show windows side-by-side" in Windows 10, without having to log out and back in again?

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer posted by Fabio Scagliola on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/show-windows-side-by-side-stacked-bug/d71ccacf-6a6e-4ca0-a4b4-57498592efb8?auth=1)

Using the Task Manager:

1. End the "Windows Shell Experience Host" process (it will be automatically restarted at once).
2. Restart the "Windows Explorer" process.

Comment: Well sadly this doesn't work, I tried everything posted here, no luck.. seems windows really broke it..

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

1. Go to Start > Settings > System > Multitasking
2. Under Snap, turn off the third option which reads "When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it."
3. Then restart your computer.
4. After restart, it should now uses the whole screen.

Enjoy!

Comment: This solved this issue for me.

Comment: Well saldy 20H2 broke it.. like what.. no workaround for now

Comment: This worked for me on Win10Pro 21H1, no reboot needed (except "Snap next to it" was the second out of three options)